# Accelerate a UIView using a UIPushBehavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, physics-engine

I'm trying to accelerate a UIView over a time/distance. So far it seems that `UIPushBehavior` is continuous, i.e it doesn't stop until it hits an immovable object. Is there a way to accelerate a `UIView` over time? or a distance?

P.S I'm not great in terms of physics vernacular, so please be kind haha

Comment: For example, say I want to accelerate a spaceship 100 points every time a user taps on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you want to slow down the push over time, so that a single push translates to some finite distance traveled, you have to (a) add a linear `resistance` (so it slows down); and (b) use `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous` (so it doesn't keep pushing). To add `resistance`, you would add a `UIDynamicItemBehavior`:

   ```
   UIDynamicItemBehavior *resistanceBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewToAnimate]];
   resistanceBehavior.resistance = 1.0;
   [self.animator addBehavior:resistanceBehavior];
   ```

   In terms of controlling the distance that each push generates, that's a combination of (a) the magnitude of the `pushDirection` vector you employ; (b) the `resistance` you apply to your item in the `UIDynamicItemBehavior`; (c) the size of item you're moving; and (d) the `density` you apply to your item in `UIDynamicItemBehavior`. It's probably best to play around with those variables until you achieve the desired distance for a single push.
2. If, on the other hand, you want to "accelerate a `UIView` over time", then rather than a `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous`, you would apply a `UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous`. By continuously applying a force, it will continue to accelerate in the `pushDirection` until that `UIPushBehavior` is removed from the `UIDynamicAnimator`.

Comment: Hey @rob -- can you attach a "spring" in Dynamics?  So, we start at 0,0.  You add a UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous, let's say to the left. the spring concept will make it, well, behave like a spring, it will bounce back and fore ultimately settling again at 0,0.  This is possible with UIKit Dynamics?  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow You can achieve spring effects in a couple of ways, but I'm not sure it makes sense within the context of a push behavior. It makes more sense in the context of a `UIAttachmentBehavior` (generally linked to some continuous gesture) or a `UISnapBehavior` (generally linked to a discrete gesture). If you're still unclear after researching/experimenting with those behaviors, I'd suggest you post a new question, rather than discussing further in the comments here.

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for the reply.  I've got the perfect example, making a "wrong-shake" the same physics as UIKit Dynamics ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356051  (unrelated to gestures; the app initiates it in this case)  Cheers!

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant. Yes, you can achieve that with attachment behavior and push behavior, tho I'd use block-based animation, personally. See my answer to that other question.